# Acumatica API: Using CR303000.Actions.ConverToCustomer

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to use the Acumatica API to convert a Business Account to a Customer on Acumatica 5.20.2067.  The code I'm using is based on [converting a Lead to a Business Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34444593/acumatica-api-using-actionconverttobaccount-for-converting-lead-is-failing).  Converting a Business Account to a Customer seems simpler than converting a Lead because converting a Business Account does not pop up a dialog box.  However, I've tried it two ways and one produces an error and the other creates a completely separate Customer record instead of converting the existing Business Account.

Based on the code in the other post about converting a Lead, here is the code that I think should work:

```
Public Function ConvertBusinessAccountToCustomer(ByVal baID As String, ByVal firstName As String, ByVal LastName As String)
    Dim CR303000 As CR303000Content = m_context.CR303000GetSchema()
    m_context.CR303000Clear()
    Dim AR303000 As AR303000Content = m_context.AR303000GetSchema()
    m_context.AR303000Clear()

    ' call the Action to convert the BA to a Customer
    Dim baKeyVal As Value = CreateValue(CR303000.AccountSummary.BusinessAccount, baID)
    Dim updateBACommands As Command() = {baKeyVal, CR303000.Actions.ConverToCustomer}
    Dim updateBaResult As CR303000Content() = m_context.CR303000Submit(updateBACommands)

    ' just like with Lead, the Customer record now needs to be saved
    ' add other fields required for Customer
    Dim customerNameVal As Value = CreateValue(AR303000.CustomerSummary.CustomerName, CreateCustomerFullName(firstName, LastName))
    Dim classVal As Value = CreateValue(AR303000.GeneralInfoFinancialSettings.CustomerClass, "DEFAULT")
    Dim statementCycleVal As Value = CreateValue(AR303000.GeneralInfoFinancialSettings.StatementCycleID, "ENDOFMONTH")
    Dim statementTypeVal As Value = CreateValue(AR303000.BillingSettingsPrintAndEmailSettings.StatementType, "Open Item")
    Dim cashDiscountAccountVal As Value = CreateValue(AR303000.GLAccountsCashDiscountAccount.CashDiscountAccount, "10103")
    Dim creditVerificationVal As Value = CreateValue(AR303000.GeneralInfoCreditVerificationRulesCreditVerification.CreditVerification, "Disabled")
    Dim commandsCustomer As Command() =
        {
            customerNameVal, classVal, statementCycleVal, statementTypeVal, cashDiscountAccountVal, creditVerificationVal,
            AR303000.Actions.Save,
            AR303000.CustomerSummary.CustomerID
        }
    Dim newCustomerContent As AR303000Content() = m_context.AR303000Submit(commandsCustomer)
    Dim newCustomerID As String = ""
    If newCustomerContent.Length > 0 Then
        ' this should be exact same as the newBAID, this is just for debugging
        newCustomerID = newCustomerContent(0).CustomerSummary.CustomerID.Value
    End If
    Return newCustomerID
End Function
```

The result though is that when CR303000Submit is called with the ConverToCustomer action, I get the following error referring to the Default Location Value:

```
[SoapException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. 
---> PX.Data.PXFieldValueProcessingException: Error: An error occurred while processing the field Default Location value 15497 Error: Default Location '15497' cannot be found in the system.. --->     PX.Data.PXSetPropertyException: Error: DefLocationID '15497' cannot be found in the system.
at PX.Data.PXSelectorAttribute.throwNoItem(String[] restricted, Boolean external, Object value)
at PX.Data.PXSelectorAttribute.FieldVerifying(PXCache sender, PXFieldVerifyingEventArgs e)
at PX.Data.PXCache.OnFieldVerifying(String name, Object row, Object& newValue, Boolean externalCall)
at PX.Data.PXCache`1.a(TNode& A_0)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Insert(Object data, Boolean bypassinterceptor)
at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Insert(Object data, Boolean bypassinterceptor)
at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Insert(Object data)
at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Extend[Parent](Parent item)
at PX.Objects.CR.BusinessAccountMaint.ConverToCustomer(PXAdapter adapter)
at PX.Data.PXAction`1.a(PXAdapter A_0)
at PX.Data.PXAction`1.<Press>d__c.MoveNext()
at PX.Data.PXAction`1.<Press>d__c.MoveNext()
at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.SyStep.CommitChanges(Object itemToBypass, PXFilterRow[] targetConditions, PXFilterRow[] filtersForAction)
at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.ExportTableHelper.ExportTable()
at PX.Api.ScreenUtils.Submit(String screenId, Command[] commands, SchemaMode schemaMode, PXGraph& graph, String& redirectContainerView, String& redirectScreen, Boolean mobile, Dictionary`2 viewFilters)
at PX.Api.Services.ScreenService.Submit(String id, IEnumerable`1 commands, SchemaMode schemaMode, Boolean mobile, PXGraph& forceGraph, String& redirectContainerView, String& redirectScreen, Dictionary`2 viewFilters)
at PX.Api.Services.ScreenService.Submit(String id, IEnumerable`1 commands, SchemaMode schemaMode)
at PX.Api.Soap.Screen.ScreenGate.Submit(Command[] commands)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---]
          System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724

Source Error
Line 1555:        <System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://www.acumatica.com/generic/CR303000/Submit", RequestNamespace:="http://www.acumatica.com/generic/", ResponseNamespace:="http://www.acumatica.com/generic/", Use:=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle:=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)>  _
Line 1556:        Public Function CR303000Submit(ByVal commands() As Command) As <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute("SubmitResult"), System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Content")> CR303000Content()
Line 1557:            Dim results() As Object = Me.Invoke("CR303000Submit", New Object() {commands})
Line 1558:            Return CType(results(0),CR303000Content())
Line 1559:        End Function
```

The other thing I tried was to change the commands for the CR303000Submit to add a Save action:
        Dim updateBACommands As Command() = {baKeyVal, CR303000.Actions.ConverToCustomer, CR303000.Actions.Save}

That gets me past that line without an error, but then when I call the AR303000Submit it just creates a separate Customer record with a different Customer/Business Account ID rather than converting the existing Business Account.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here:

> An error occurred while processing the field Default Location value 15497 Error: Default Location '15497' cannot be found in the system.

I think this is your data problem. Login with browser and check this Business Account manually. I think you will receive same error.

> Convert To Customer action problem

This action produce redirect. It is a problem. But there is a solution:

- Create new customization Project
- Create GraphExtension for Grapth "BusinessAccountMaint"
- Insert next code

  using System;
  using System.Collections;
  using Avalara.AvaTax.Adapter.AvaCert2Service;
  using PX.Common;
  using PX.Data;
  using PX.Data.EP;
  using PX.Objects.AP;
  using PX.Objects.CS;
  using PX.Objects.CT;
  using PX.Objects.SO;
  using PX.SM;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using PX.Objects;
  using PX.Objects.CR;

  namespace PX.Objects.CR
  {
      public class BusinessAccountMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension
      {

  ```
      public PXAction<BAccount> convertToCustomerAndSave;

      // hidden action. Used in API calls
      [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Convert To Customer And Save", Visible = false, MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
      [PXButton(ImageKey = PX.Web.UI.Sprite.Main.Process)]
      public virtual IEnumerable ConvertToCustomerAndSave(PXAdapter adapter)
      {
          try
          {
              return Base.ConverToCustomer(adapter);
          }
          catch (PXRedirectRequiredException e) // catch redirect exception
          {
              (e.Graph as AR.CustomerMaint).Save.Press(); // Save our new customer

              return adapter.Get();
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  }
- Save and Publish
- Regenerate Service Reference (WSDL)
- Use new action in your cade

  ```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      var client = new ScreenSoapClient();

      client.Login("admin", "123");

      var baSchema = client.CR303000GetSchema();

      var commands = new Command[]
      {
          new Value
          {
              Value = "MAURICES",
              LinkedCommand = baSchema.AccountSummary.BusinessAccount
          },
          baSchema.Actions.ConvertToCustomerAndSave // use our new action instead of default
      };

      client.CR303000Submit(commands);
  }
  ```
- This code will convert Business Account to Customer and Save it immediately